# Stationary Process

Tags: stationarity

I have some questions about stationary process and its statistical properties. If $\{X_t\}$ is a stationary process, then do the following equations hold?
($j$ is a integer)

$$\operatorname{E}[X_t]=\operatorname{E}[X_{t-j}]$$

$$\operatorname{Var}[X_t]=\operatorname{Var}[X_{t-j}]$$

Is $\{X_tX_{t-j}\}$ a stationary process?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is only partial, but I hope it helps.

---

It depends on whether you are referring to a strictly (strong) stationary process or a weakly stationary process.

In the case of a strictly stationary process, the probabilistic behavior of a series will be identical to that of that series at any number of lags.

However, since this is a very strong assumption, the word "stationary" is often used to refer to weak stationarity. In this case, the expectation must be constant and not dependent on time *t*. The autocovariance must depend solely on the lag, *j*. Though this provides useful properties, it does not guarantee that the series' expectations and variances will be the same.